# facebook comment box formatting height:590px

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-comments

On the iPad, facebook comment box automatically sets a height of 590px. The initial view is just the login button so it's much too large. I can't set a height in css because once they log-in, then the content area will be too small, and fb doesn't set any classes I could hook into under those conditions.

In the  I have:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=00000000";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And within the content area:

```
<div id="fb_comments">
    <fb:comments href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" num_posts="10" width="500">    </fb:comments>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: i have same problem. interesting to know the fix for this.

Comment: Never found a solution. Resolved to scrap FB commenting based on schedule.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I use to work around this is to put the facebook comments div inside of a parent div, set the max-height of the parent div and overflow to scroll.

**example:**

HTML:
parent div:

```
<div id="fb-comments-container"><!-- comments plugin goes here --></div>
```

CSS:

```
#fb-comments-container {
max-height: 300px;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could use JQuery to solve this. 
Check if the user is connected. If he is, then set the height to 590px, else set it to whatever you want.

You can do that by adding the [JQuery plugin](http://jquery.com/) and then doing something like `$('.fb:comments').css('height', 'YourValuepx');`

Anyway, i don't know if this type of plugin can be used in a mobile. there is also a mobile version of the JQuery plugin, but i don't have any experience on it: [JQuery mobile](http://api.jquerymobile.com/)